# Python Webscraping Multiple Pages Out of Range

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping, export-to-csv

After extracting the json file where I get most of the reviews information for that website. I want to do the same thing but for all of its pages. Why is it giving me an index out of range in this case

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from random import randint
from time import sleep

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"}
url="https://www.zomato.com/beirut/deek-duke-ashrafieh/reviews?page=1&sort=dd&filter=reviews-dd"

for page in range(1,10): 
    req = requests.get('https://www.zomato.com/beirut/deek-duke-ashrafieh/reviews?page=' + str(page) + '&sort=dd&filter=reviews-dd')
    soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
    info = soup.find_all("script",attrs={"type": "application/ld+json"})
    print(info)
    sleep(randint(2,10))
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question: what is your end goal, what are you trying to obtain?

Comment: It's giving me an out of range index. I want to extract the json file of all pages, I'm looping through every page to extract it

Answer (score 0):

You defined `titles` as all `<script type="application/ld+json">` tags on that page. And then you looped through a range from 4 to 19, asking for information such as `titles[i].text`: as there are only 3 such script tags on that page, you are receiving this error. Depending on your end goal, you may want to review Dev tools - network tab, and maybe find a JSON endpoint returning the data you're looking for.

Comment: So I re-arranged the code this time it is giving me empty lists

Comment: I believe I answered your question as it was posed initially. If you have a new question, do not edit entirely your question (as you did in this case, rendering my response moot), but ask a new one.To avoid an eventual X-Y Problem, think about your end goal, and what would be shortest, cleanest path to reach it. I gave you a hint in the comment above: inspect the XHR calls made by the scripts on that page.